# Examples of almost Dedekind domains that are not Dedekind

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domains

All I know about almost Dedekind domains (which I have come to learn about only recently) is that they are integral domains whose localization at every prime is a discrete valuation ring. In other words one of the equivalent conditions for an integral domain to be a Dedekind domain is that it is Noetherian amd every prime localization is a DVR, and for almost Dedekind domains we just remove the condition of Noetherian-ness. Since coming to learn of this, I have been extremely interested to find a non-trivial example of an almost Dedekind domain (i.e. an almost Dedekind domain which is not Dedekind). After several searches, the only example I could come across is that given by N. Nakano in a 1953 paper, wherein we consider the infinite extension of the field of rational numbers, obtained by adjoining all the $p$-th roots of unity. Surprisingly, despite a somewhat extensive search and a few attempts at obtaining such domains by taking the compositum of infinitely many algebraic extensions, I have found no other example of almost Dedekind domains that are not Dedekind. I would really appreciate more examples of this or a few references containing the same.

Comment: It's easy to produce similar examples: if $R$ is a Dedekind domain with infinitely many primes (say even Jacobson), and $R \to R_i$ are finite separable extensions such that each $\mathfrak p \subseteq R$ is only ramified in finitely many $R_i$, then the integral closure $S$ of $R$ in a compositum of the fraction fields of the $R_i$ is a ring whose localisations are DVRs. If you have infinitely many $R_i$, then $S$ will not be Noetherian, as the extended ideals $\mathfrak pS$ have height $1$ but contain infinitely many prime ideals.

Comment: It's possible that I'm missing or overstating hypotheses, but some examples are the integral closure of $\mathbf Z$ in $\mathbf Q(\{\sqrt{p}\ |\ p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \text{ prime}\}$ and the integral closure of $\mathbf C[x]$ in $\mathbf C(x)[\{\sqrt{x-a}\ |\ a \in \mathbf C\}]$. Basically the thing that would keep the localisations from being DVRs is if they are infinitely ramified and therefore have non-discrete value group, like what happens in the Prüfer domain $\bar{\mathbf Z}$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Sorry I haven't seen much of infinitely ramified extensions, how do I show that these extensions are not infinitely ramified?

Comment: No, you get $\mathbf Z\left[\left\{\tfrac{1+\sqrt{p}}{2}\ \big|\ p \text{ prime}, p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}\right\}\right]$, since $\mathbf Z\left[\tfrac{1+\sqrt{p}}{2}\right]$ is ramified exactly at $p$ and $R_1 \otimes_{\mathbf Z} R_2$ is a normal domain if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rings of integers that ramify at disjoint sets of primes (in particular, $\operatorname{Frac}(R_1)$ and $\operatorname{Frac}(R_2)$ are linearly disjoint under these hypotheses). Then $\sqrt{p}$ (resp. $p$) is a uniformiser at any prime $\mathfrak p$ above $p$ if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ (resp. $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$).

Comment: Hint: show that a filtered colimit ('union') of DVRs along generically finite local unramified maps is a DVR (with the same uniformiser at each level). That reduces the question to something about number rings.

Comment: There is a long list of examples in K.A. Loper:
*Almost Dedekind domains which are not Dedekind.* In:
Multiplicative Ideal Theory in Commutative Algebra, Springer (2006), pp. 279-292